Opengraph works on page but doesnt show on share, @vercel/og
Summary
So i am using Next.js 13 pages router, i want to implement a dynamic og:image on my meta tags. I created an API handler that generates the image from id that i get from searchParams.
It all worked flawlessly on my browser (see image-1), but when i deployed it to vercel, and tried to share the link or use Facebook's Meta Debugger, it doesn't show the values.

Code
This is my simplified implementation for both of the [id]/page.tsx:
// client

export default function Product() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const { property, isLoading } = useProperty(Number(id));

  const title = property ? `${NAME} | ${property.name_formatted}` : `${NAME}`;
  const description = property ? property.description : "Empty property description";
  const currentUrl = `${BASE_URL}/api/og?id=${id}`;

  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo
        title={title}
        description={description}
        openGraph={{
          title,
          description,
          images: [
            {
              url: currentUrl,
              width: 1200,
              height: 630,
              alt: title,
            },
          ],
          siteName: NAME,
        }}
      />
      {/* Additional Codes */}
    </>
  );
}

And for /api/og.tsx:
// api handler

import { ImageResponse } from "@vercel/og";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export const config = { runtime: "edge" };

async function fetchProperty(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}/properties/${id}`);
  return response.json();
}

export default async function handler(req: NextRequest) {
  const id = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
  if (!id) return new Response("Missing ID", { status: 400 });

  const property = await fetchProperty(id);
  if (!property) return new Response("Property not found", { status: 404 });

  return new ImageResponse(
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", padding: "24px" }}>
      <h1>{property.name}</h1>
      <img src={property.imageUrl} alt={property.name} />
    </div>,
    { width: 1200, height: 630 }
  );
}

What I've Tried
I implemented next-seo but it didn't work, I think it's because of the [id]/page.tsx being a client-side file, the og:image is only loaded on the browser instead of the server

The Facebook scraper doesn't execute any client-side JavaScript; you need some sort of server-side pre-rendering solution for this.
